# Saturday evening taxi availability in Manteigas

Tags: taxis, portugal

On the evening of Saturday 21 April, I will need to take a taxi out of the [Serra de Estrela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serra_da_Estrela) to the [train station in Mangualde](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Ferrovi%C3%A1ria_de_Mangualde) (in order to catch the [Sud Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Express) to France).  I'm not sure where I will take it from.  From [Seia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seia), [Gouveia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouveia_Municipality,_Portugal), or [Covilhã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covilh%C3%A3), I'm quite confident I'll be able to find a taxi.  But I might end my hike in [Manteigas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manteigas), which is much smaller and located in the middle of the park.  Should I expect to be able to find a taxi in Manteigas on a Saturday evening?

Answer (score 2):

You will most probably get a taxi easily; while Manteigas is small, it has a good road accessibility for getting out of Serra da Estrela.

However, please note that Manteigas is on the opposite side of the Serra from Mangualde. It would be more sensible, nearer and cheaper being in Seia or Gouveia, if you could change your plans.

Taxis also work pretty much any time of the week or day (or night). The location is however small, and you might have to call them by phone.  On the other hand, being the location small, you might also be able to walk to the "Praça de taxis", where usually 3 to 5 taxis are waiting for customers.

It might be wise booking a time and place to be picked up for improving your chances of getting on time.

Searching in the Internet, this seems to be the number of a local taxi service:  +351 275 982 868  - Táxi de Silva Carvalho & Monte

If hosted in a local accommodation, ask them to call/book the taxi for you, they will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Regarding your PS: I intend to take the train to Hendaye and then on to Paris. I don't want to take an overnight coach as I prefer the comfort of a bed on an overnight train. I'm aware the trains are slow there, but the [Sud Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Express) is a classic train and should be an interesting experience!  I expect the taxis in Portugal to be relatively cheap for someone used to northern European prices.

Comment: @gerrit Thanks for the input, I am taking the PS comment out then. Taxis can start getting slightly more expensive over long distances. The taxi will have to avoid the Serra roads if already night time. Be sure to ask how long they usually take previously to make your plans.

Comment: Oh, regarding your last comment, do you mean some roads are closed at night necessitating a substantial detour?

Comment: When I was there last month I avoiding driving at night in the mountain roads...I guess a sensible person would have to go around, and probably will as they can drive faster. Locals drove like madmen in the mountain roads, but I guess even them have to go around in the dead of night. But I might be wrong. It might be wiser leaving earlier with daylight and having a relaxed dinner near the train station.

Comment: Although I suspect the taxi drivers may be a subset of "local madmen" I will consider your advice in my travel plans!

Comment: @gerrit out of topic, from my tripadvisor profile https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g666185-d2137817-r548463369-Descanso_Serrano-Manteigas_Guarda_District_Central_Portugal.htm and https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g580265-d4875458-r548152633-Serra_da_Estrela-Serra_da_Estrela_Guarda_District_Central_Portugal.html